# Adding an inner wrapper div to an HTML page

Tags: html, css, web

I'm coding a website, and I have the basics, but I want an easy-to-implement middle inner wrapper div to hold the contents of the site. I'm not super experienced with CSS and I can't find any relevant help.

I want the end result to look like this- http://i.imgur.com/vkBzWsk.jpg?1

I looked around in the code, but it seemed insane to dig through over 300 lines of code for hours to look for a way to add a white square in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a [simple JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/we4f6658/4/) example you can run, modify and inspect.

Take a look, in order for this to work you need to have your containing elements (html, body) to have 100% width and height

```
html, body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Then you can simply use percentages for the white thingy, the simplified version looks like this:

```
#whiteInnerDivThing{
  width:60%;
  height:30%;
  margin-top:50%;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

Also I've added rounded corners and inset drop shadow in the example so it's nicer. BTW I like Jazza too :D

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very simple, just a few lines of css code:

```
div{
width:60%;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
background-color:red;
}
```

Here is a full html example according to your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://i.imgur.com/Bj3KBRt.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<title>Welcome to Wumbo.Net!</title>
<body>
<style>
<style>
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #00ffaa;
}

::selection {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #00ffaa;
}
</style>
<style>
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #00ffaa;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #00d486;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #57ffd5;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #00ffaa;
}
#center{
width:60%;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
background-color:white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body background="http://i.imgur.com/hySVC7M.png">
<div id="center">
<center>
<h1><font face="trebuchet MS" color="dbdbdb">This Site is Under Construction!</h1>
<p>In a few months, when I am finished, I will unveil this site! In the meantime,
also for updates, follow me on twitter.
<br>
I also have a Youtube channel where I upload stupid crap!</p>
<br>
<h1> MY SOCIAL NETWORKZ</h1>
<br>
<a href="https://twitter.com/BullCloaker">Twitter</a>
<br>
<a href="https://youtube.com/user/calluvdutyplayr9"> My Youtube Channel</a>
<br>
<a href="https://wumbotheelephant.newgrounds.com"> My Newgrounds (I'm not super active on it) </a>
<br>
<p> I'm not sure what I'm going to do with this site,
<br>
But it will most likely be a portfolio, where I share all the drawings,
<br>
animations and other such things I've made.
<br>
Seeya!
<br>
<font face="trebuchet MS" color="#00ffaa"> ~Wumbo</font>
</font>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br> <font color="dbdbdb">//!This is empty space to the skin customizer, this space is safe for content, feel free to use!\\</font>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<font face="trebuchet MS" color="#00ffaa" size="2">You are currently using the Dark Site Skin.<a href="file:///C:/Users/jeanpaul/Desktop/websites/index.html">Click Here to use the Light Site Skin</a>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I don't know if you''ve used it or not, but [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/) is a really good website for html/css/javascript (all of the above). It has tutorials and references!

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I'm having trouble getting this into my code, do you mind helping inserting this into my code? Here's my site- (BTW, I know that some of my links there are local, they're just placeholders) http://pastebin.com/NR5uHnhs **P.S. I love w3schools, but I didn't think I saw anything relevant, I may have been wrong and just not had the correct context.**

Comment: So my guess is that you are looking to add a opaqe background behind the txt, but don't want it all the way accross?

Comment: Yes, I can customize the length across and such, you don't have to deal with that, I just want it to be able to show up and be on the correct layer.

Comment: Ok, I've updated it in the code, with a white background. And I almost lost the center tags, but I added them again. Heads up, they have been deprecated in HTML5

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me out a lot, I'll be sure to give you credit in a credits page of the site in a few months :D

Comment: wohoo! It honestly doesn't matter, but thanks for your thoughts.